# VCL style theme cutting form borders when maximized

Tags: delphi, themes, vcl

Delphi version: 10.1 update 2 (Berlin)

When applying a vcl theme to an application. When maximizing the form, it removes the borders causing border-aligned objects like: labels, menus, buttons to have a "cut" part.
In the example in question, the theme has a 6-pixel border (left, right, bottom).

You may also notice that the title bar appears with the top "cut off".

Is there any way to get around this situation, and make sure that the measures of borders and title bar are respected as specified in the theme?

Normal Window

[image: Normal window]

Maximized Window

[image: Maximized window]

Unit1.pas

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Menus;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    MainMenu1: TMainMenu;
    este1: TMenuItem;
    este2: TMenuItem;
    este3: TMenuItem;
    este4: TMenuItem;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Unit1.dfm

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 441
  ClientWidth = 704
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  Menu = MainMenu1
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Position = poScreenCenter
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 704
    Height = 13
    Align = alTop
    Caption = 'Novo Teste'
  end
  object Label2: TLabel
    Left = 0
    Top = 428
    Width = 704
    Height = 13
    Align = alBottom
    Caption = 'Novo Teste'
  end
  object Label3: TLabel
    Left = 0
    Top = 13
    Width = 704
    Height = 13
    Align = alTop
    Alignment = taRightJustify
    Caption = 'Novo Teste'
  end
  object Label4: TLabel
    Left = 0
    Top = 415
    Width = 704
    Height = 13
    Align = alBottom
    Alignment = taRightJustify
    Caption = 'Novo Teste'
  end
  object MainMenu1: TMainMenu
    Left = 384
    Top = 152
    object este1: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Teste'
      object este2: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Teste'
      end
      object este3: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Teste'
      end
      object este4: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Teste'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please show the `.dfm` file content and any related code (if there is any), so we can reproduce the issue. Also inform which Windows version, and any personal display settings, if any.

Comment: This is probably covered by following bug report https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14081 fixed in Delphi 10.4

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar from what I saw it is exactly the same case reported in RSP-14081. But upgrading to Delphi 10.4 is not an alternative at the moment.

Comment: To some extent you can solve it for the labels (and also other components that you want to keep aligned to the borders) in your example with `Align with margins` and setting the `margins` as needed ( I tested with left and right margin as 6, while top and bottom as 0. Result was not perfect but maybe acceptable for now).